# How to control webpages via PHP?

Tags: php

I want to login into a website, make some choices there, submit and logout.

Not so impressive by itself, but I want to do it with PHP. And without cURL, as it is not installed on my server.

How do I do it?

Comment: Without cURL you're going to have to implement your own cURL clone using PHP's socket functions. Can you ask for cURL to be installed?

Comment: No, cURL cannot be installed. In general, what cURL can do, file_get_contents can do aswell.

Comment: Except for submit post requests, which will be vital if your logging in to websites. And if it's done over https, that adds another layer of complexity.

Comment: go to http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php, search for file_post_contents. Dude, I need to know IN GENERAL how to control a website. Is there a gui which outputs the code necessary after performing all the steps like imacros?

Comment: You can embed an `img` tag that is really a PHP script on a remote server that does have cURL! If anything qualifies as a hack, this is it.

Comment: @Tobias Sanger It really depends on what sites you're logging in to and what you're doing there. If you can be more specific we can be more helpful.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder i want to login into bod.de

Comment: @Zach Rattner Please give me an example how that works.

Comment: @Tobias Sanger Would it be possible to link to the actual login page?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder http://pastebin.com/uHbjpJpR might help, this is what imacros does.

Answer (score 1):

without cURL, you'll need to use PHP's Stream functions, which can accomplish the same things, if with slightly more code.  Start with [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) and work your way through the manual

Comment: I need to convert http://pastebin.com/uHbjpJpR to stream_context_create, how would you do it?

Comment: It's not something I have a lot of experience with, you'll need to read the manual.  You can also do it with the socket functions.  Google "stream_context_create http post" for another starting point