# How to create a zombie server in php?

Tags: php, proxy

I want to create a zombie server.

That means, it is a proxy server being controlled by another server.

The reason is that my server neither supports ssl nor curl. And another server does. So I want to pass php-orders to the other server(which understands php) via php-paramater (index.php?order=...) and the result to be sent to my script.

Is there a snippet available for the zombie server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly unsecure and untested, but I believe something like that would suit your needs.

Server 1 (that without curl etc.):

```
<?php

// hash from pass, eg. 'da790439c0d433fcb1c1528008a1df2b5a7a7051'
$hash = sha1('some password here');
$command = 'echo "aaa";';
$result = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/?hash='.$hash.'&command='.urlencode($command));
```

Server 2 (that with curl):

```
<?php

// hashed password hash
$hashed_hash = 'eb6874cc5accb7ab24c1ce4a6ec5521ac5748340';
if (isset($_GET['hash']) && sha1($_GET['hash'])==$hashed_hash) {
    // correct hash given
    $command = urldecode($_GET['command']);
    // do whatever you need with command
}
```

Comment: hmm, that is moderately insecure. As this will be a decent applications I think it is not a good way to go. My goal is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884678/how-to-control-webpages-via-php . Which approach do you recommend over using a zombie server?

Comment: @Tobias Sanger: I would probably suggest using some functions stored on the Server no. 2 (with curl) and calling these functions as Web Services with SOAP (see [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), PHP has support for this), or calling Server no. 2 with [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) through secure connection, if you want something simple. I would avoid sending PHP code through the Internet - you can store it on Server no. 2 and just call it when needed. Is it clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) with a HTTP resource provided that the [fopen() wrappers are enabled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

```
if (($sResult = @file_get_contents('http://zombie.example.net/order.php?order=…')) === FALSE) {
    throw new Exception('HTTP request failed!');
}
```

You then can parse `$sResult`.

Still, be sure to know that you are sending possibly sensitive information in plain-text to the "zombie" before the request is protected via SSL there.

At the zombie in `order.php` script, you simply process the `$_GET` parameters and put them into a SSL request, using either cURL or `file_get_contents()` again.